# Make a line into a string

Tags: python

I got a bot from [this](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/1968) website, and I've been having a lot of fun with it. However I wanted to add an away command.
The way it's gonna work is that when someone write

```
 away [reason]
```

then it saves the reason, and when someone else types his name, the bot sais "He is not available, he left a note '[reason]'" or something like that.
The input I get when someone writes to the bot is

```
 :NickName!email@gtanet-GTMJLJRI83.nextgentel.com
 PRIVMSG #mychat :away Im going
 fishing.
```

Using this

```
 line[0][line[0].index(":")+1:line[0].index("!")]
```

I got the username of the person (in this case, it's NickName), and I need to extract all lines after away, using line[4:] (Im going fishing), and that works like a charm.
But I need to make it into a string, because it can't return a string and a list.

**tl;dr**    I get a list as a value, and I want it to return it with a string, what do I do?

Comment: Instead of teal dearing yourself, just show us what you have, and how you want it.

Comment: is your input a string? a list of strings?

Comment: From the way he is using it, I'd say that `line` is a list of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want like this:

```
line = [
    ':NickName!email@gtanet-GTMJLJRI83.nextgentel.com',
    'PRIVMSG #mychat :away Im going',
    'fishing.'
]

away = '\n'.join(line[1:])
needle = ':away '
away = away[away.index(needle) + len(needle):]
print away
```

Result:

```
Im going
fishing.
```

If you want the output on one line use `' '.join(line[1:])` instead of `'\n'.join(line[1:])`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn a list into a string just use `'x'.join(mylist)`, where x is the character you want between each element (such as a space, comma, etc.), then you can just concatenate that with your other string.

I though I guess there are two different ways, but I'm not sure which is faster (or if you'll be doing it enough to make a difference)

```
...
mylist.append(mystr)
return ' '.join(mylist)
```

and

```
...
return ' '.join(mylist) + ' ' + mystr
```

though I think the former way looks better.

**edit:**
If your list contains non-strings you can feed a generator expression to `.join()`:

```
return ' '.join(str(_) for _ in mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a list of strings you can just do:

```
''.join(stringlist)
```

which concatenates all the strings, making it one string.

See [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)